# Git Revert a few commits (including merges) then recommit them later

Tags: git, version-control, git-revert

I have a staging server where I update the code using `git pull` from the git server. One detail here which may or may not be relevant is that at some point it started happening that every time I pull it asks me to merge. I haven't had enough time to figure out why yet. Anyways, if I look at `git log` there is a merge after every pull. Anyways, not to the real question. I just need to temporarily revert 2 previous commits (with 2 corresponding merges). I am pretty confident in how to do this using `git revert` the 2+2 = 4 hashes that appear in the git log and then committing.

The question is that I would like to then re-commit the reverts later in the future, since we will need these changes later but just not now. Do I need to do anything special so that I don't lose the commits that I revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revert` is probably **NOT** what you want; `revert` adds a new commit that undoes a set of changes. `reset` is more like it, which is for modifying branch histories, but read on before doing anything brash.

First thing I'd suggest is to try using `pull -r` to automatically rebase your local changes onto the updated `HEAD` of the branch (i.e. the remote copy of the branch).

You could also start an interactive `rebase` with `rebase -i origin/mybranch`. Rebase is git's most powerful feature that allows you to rewrite history. It's also mildly dangerous, so beware.

Tutorial on `rebase`: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

No matter what you do to your local git directory, `reflog` will let you see what previous states (commits) of your repo. It's saved my butt once or twice when I accidentally "lost" a commit when I screwed up a rebase or a reset.

Comment: I see, I realized that I don't need to actually rewrite history per-se. In fact my official source code is on the remote server. I don't want to change that. I only need to turn back a few local commits temporarily. Now I'm thinking I can revert and commit locally, then once I am ready I can just pull down again from the server which should have all the changes that I previously reverted. Do you think this would work?

Comment: Or maybe what I should do is first revert locally so I have what I need. Then once I want to go back to the original source code I can reset back to quite a few commits earlier so the local head i before the remote head and the pull again to get back up-to-date. How does this sound?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Sounds like it could work, try it!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind When you stop thinking like working with git as a step-by-step process, and start thinking of your commit history as a series of independent changes that you can reword, polish, trim, and reorder into any structure you like, you'll become what my coworker refers to as a "git Jedi" and you will no longer be plagued by these types of questions. Practice visualizing your repo history (I use [`tig`](https://github.com/jonas/tig) **OFTEN** for this), and practice using rebase. If you've ever amended a commit, you've already started on this journey. :-)

Comment: Yes thank you for that great advice. Through this problem I learned a bit about git. I realized the best thing to do would be to go back to the front of the dev cycle and make things right in the dev server and push the changes all through the pipeline. (Instead of trying to change things on the staging server) I was able to revert those bad changes I made right in the dev server using revert. I then in the staging server, reset the git history to few commits earlier and re-pulled. Boom, and voila now I am not asked to merge anymore on every pull either. Thanks for you help!